# Observe an expression from within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Basically, how can I listen to changes in an expression from within a directive?

---

I'm using the undocumented `ng-required` to conditionally require a certain field:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="partner" checked />
<input ng-model="partnerName" placeholder="required" ng-required="partner" />
```

This works great ([here's the Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBDguOh1BUh37DbugCJb?p=preview)). The only problem with this is that it keeps the `placeholder` "required" text, regardless of whether it's actually required.

---

So, I decided to create my own directive. Here's how it should work:

```
<input ng-placeholder="{ 'required': partner }" />
```

The idea is similar to angular's `ng-class`, but I have no way how to accomplish this. Here's what I've got so far:

```
app.directive('ngPlaceholder', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log( scope.$eval(attrs.ngPlaceholder) );
        }
    }
});
```

which logs a nice object that I can use to determine the `placeholder` value:

```
{ required: true }
```

but how do I then hook into the `$digest`/`$apply` cycle to update the `placeholder` attribute whenever `partner` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/83wZy086dHDl1r9EDAcS)

the basic idea for your link function should be like

```
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.xngPlaceholder, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
          element.removeAttr('placeholder');
          var att = '';
           angular.forEach(newVal, function (elm, key)
                att += elm ? (key + ' ') : ''; 
            });
            element.attr('placeholder', att);
        }, true);
    }
```

Comment: One suggestion: don't use ng- prefix since it's angulars, unless you know that in a future version they will implement ng-placeholder with the same syntax

Comment: Thanks ! That's true. However I just use original post's code.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, that does not require a directive:

```
placeholder="{{{true: 'required', false:''}[partner]}}"
```

The above creates object `{true: 'required', false:''}` and then indexes into the object using the current value of `partner`.